# Python loop through a list to find a substring match in another string from a column in dataframe then return that matched substring in a new column

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, if-statement

I am programming in Python 3.6 on Spyder 3.2.3 on MacOS Sierra 10.12.6.

I have a column in a dataframe `df` containing a list of towns in Australia and other information. The column of interest is `suburbs`

```
df["suburbs"]

Apollo Bay (Tas.)
Apollo Bay (Vic.)
Apoinga
ACT Remainder - Belconni
```

I also have a list `states` containing the states in Australia.

```
states = ["NSW", "VIC", "TAS", "ACT", "SA", "WA"]
```

My objective is to see whether a suburb from the `df["suburbs"]`contains any state from the list `states` and if yes, then it will return the state in column `df["state"]`.

So, at the moment my solution is to use for loop and if statement, however, for some reason my for loop and if statement returns `not found` to every line even if it matches. My current for loop and if statement is below:

```
for suburb in df["suburbs"].str.upper():
    for state in states:
        if state in suburb:
            df["state"] = state
        else:
            df["state"] = "not found"
```

And this returns

```
not found
not found
not found
not found
```

Another thing I noticed is on the variable explorer section of the Spyder, the above code creates 2 variables `suburb` and `state` with values `ACT Remainder - Belconni` and `WA`, respectively. It seems to pick the last values from both the dataframe column and list.

However, if I do not create a new column `state` and just use `print` function to see if the substring matches, it shows that it actually works. Code is below:

```
for suburb in test["suburbs"].str.upper():
    for state in states:
        if state in suburb:
            print(suburb, state)
```

And the result is:

```
APOLLO BAY (TAS.) TAS
APOLLO BAY (VIC.) VIC
ACT REMAINDER - BELCONNI ACT
```

It skips the one that doesn't have the match. But as soon as I add an additional `else` statement to print `not found` the result will be all `not found`. Can anyone please help me understand what is wrong here and why? It's pretty frustrating because it seems to me to be a simple task.

Thank you so much.

Comment: `df["state"] = state` is assigning the values of the *entire column* to be equal to the state or to "not found" if not found - so you're over-writing the column for every row you process and that columns final value is whatever you set from processing the last row...

Comment: Does `df['state'] = df.suburbs.str.upper().str.extract('({})'.format('|'.join(states)), expand=False).fillna('not found')` do what you're after?

Comment: @JonClements ah right. my code keeps overwriting the entire `state` column with the last processed row. thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @JonClements that line you shared returned this error `invalid character in identifier`

Comment: sounds like you want to `re.escape` each of the states then in case they contain characters used in regex (they're not all just 3 letters for instance?) - hard to tell without you coming forth with more specific information though...

Comment: @JonClements sorry Jon, it worked! i copied and pasted the code to my editor straight away and it didnt work because of [zero width space] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) thank you so much for your assistance!